# How to determine the version, edition, and update level of SQL Server from the mdf file?

Tags: sql-server

I have a `.MDF` file and I want to know its version, edition and update level of SQL Server that created it.

Thanks...

Comment: Do you not know what server the MDF came from?

Comment: I Googled 'get version from mdf file' and found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an **MDF Viewer** tool (http://www.mdfviewer.com/) - which works on *some*  `.mdf` files, but not all.

What it **cannot** determine (and no other tool will, either) is the *edition* of SQL Server that created this file - the `.mdf` files are interchangeable between editions, there's nothing edition-specific about a `.mdf` file

Comment: Thank you for answer, I install mdfviewer , it show version of mdf but don't show which service pack . If I want to build a setup file in visual studio  I need to know  it's service pack to attach setup file properly prerequisites of sql server .